# React Router Match isn't showing the params

Tags: reactjs, react-router

When I enter the following url "http://localhost:8000/#/reset-password?name=saif", the match object doesn't seem to identify the parmeter shown. However, the parameter is visible in the location object, so I am unsure why this isn't working. See below for the react devtools snippet showing values for match and location.

[image: React Dev Tools]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `match.params` are parameters you define in your route paths, not a URL's query/search parameters which are located on the router context's `location` object.

Example:

For given `Route`

```
<Route path="/root/:id">
```

and URL

```
"/root/23?qp1=test"
```

Then `match.id` would be `23` and `location.search` would be `"?qp1=test"`.